# How to convert excel cell to html?

Tags: html, vba, excel

I've got an excel cell that contains html content like this:

```
What is <b>the</b> answer to <i>this</i> question?  See table <table><tr><td>....
```

You get the idea.  It's a cell that for all intensive purposes contains a webpage.

I would like to be able to view this cell's content after interpreted by a browser in some way.  I was thinking the Microsoft Web Control would be ideal, but I'm not quite sure how to go about setting the actual html of the web control.  I can navigate to web pages, but I'm not sure how to actually set the html equal to my cell's value.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

With an embedded "Microsoft Web Browser" ActiveX control named "wbTest" on the worksheet:

(code in the worksheet module)

```
Sub TestHtml()
    ShowHtml Me.Range("A1").Value
End Sub


Sub ShowHtml(s As String)
    With Me.wbTest
        .Document.Open "text/html"
        .Document.write s
        .Document.Close
    End With
End Sub
```